# How do you add a search box to the map when creating a CartoDB visualization at runtime?

Tags: carto

I know that it is possible to add the CartoDB search box when you link to a visualization [such as this](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbcreatevismapid-vizjsonurl-options--callback). However, I have a map which is created at runtime, using the same method as [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#creating-visualizations-at-runtime). Does anybody know, when a visualization is created at runtime, if there is any way to add the CartoDB search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Here is a working example,

http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/befa66fc9327f6c2908e

The key bit is instantiating the overlay and then adding it to the page, you do that with this part,

```
var v = cdb.vis.Overlay.create('search', map.viz, {})
v.show();
$('#map').append(v.render().el);
```